# Why is it "sat on my stomach" not "sat in my stomach"?

Tags: prepositions

> repeat
>   3. (of food) be tasted intermittently for some time after being swallowed as a result of belching or indigestion.
>   "it sat rather uncomfortably on my stomach and repeated on me for hours"
>   (source: [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=repeat%20definition&oq=re&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i60l3.1351j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

Since "it" here refers to consumed food, shouldn't it be "it sat **in** my stomach"?

Comment: As far as I know, it's a mistake and it *should* be **in**. Only something like a cat would sit **on** your stomach. (Note that using a Google search in this way is not a good source of authority. You should reference an actual website rather than general search results.)

Comment: I checked the ODO ([repeat](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/repeat)), as Google uses Oxford Dictionary products under license, and the definition is the same, but the example is not present. It also notes that this usage of "repeat" is "British". This usage of "on" is unusual to me, so I would guess it might be British too. Or possibly a typo, I don't know.

Comment: @Em. I have also noticed while the majority of Google Dictionary's content is from the ODO, occasionally the examples are different. My guess is the ODO updates its content and Google Dictionary possibly reflects older versions.

Comment: While it sounds wrong to me, "sat on my stomach" might be a kind of metaphorical statement, comparing the indigestion to something actually sitting on your stomach externally—like a cat.

Comment: But "That bowl of beans weighed heavily *on* my stomach" would be OK. I think that was the idea the example was going for.

Answer (score 1):

The 'on' version is correct, but is an antiquated way of speaking. [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=xOsiAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA423&lpg=PA423&dq=%22heavy%20on%20my%20stomach%22%20food&source=bl&ots=XgYTyIQcCc&sig=AkMxFoUE0qB6KPlz_jONvdih1s8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtoJPEgI7fAhUn5IMKHRR5CPgQ6AEwCnoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22heavy%20on%20my%20stomach%22%20food&f=false) [are](https://books.google.com/books?id=IBkyAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=%22heavy%20on%20my%20stomach%22%20food&source=bl&ots=SId_g13rW-&sig=SLje4Ac9v1TOZM_8bRVk_9B4CSI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtoJPEgI7fAhUn5IMKHRR5CPgQ6AEwDHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22heavy%20on%20my%20stomach%22%20food&f=false) [a few](https://books.google.com/books?id=HZIsAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA273&lpg=PA273&dq=%22heavy%20on%20my%20stomach%22%20food&source=bl&ots=SQg0X_H2qg&sig=OC0jPmovTuP84PLi9bjsIO0Dl08&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtoJPEgI7fAhUn5IMKHRR5CPgQ6AEwC3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22heavy%20on%20my%20stomach%22%20food&f=false) examples of its use. As far as I can tell, it seems to refer to foods that we consider to cause discomfort and tightness, similar to if someone was sitting on your stomach.